# New OpenGL Driver Sleeps on HDMI output

Tags: screen, lxde, screen-saver

So Im tinkering with the new (experimental) OpenGL drivers for the raspberry pi. The driver seems to work somewhat so far, but has a really aggravating issue which only happens when the OpenGL support is enabled, and has been reproduced on multiple HDMI monitors. The colour palette screen

[rpi palette screen http://rpi2.fatdog.eu/images/rpi2-rainbowsplashscreen.jpg](http://rpi2.fatdog.eu/images/rpi2-rainbowsplashscreen.jpg)

that shows up at boot initially disappears while the boot messages scroll by on the console, but once the desktop is active, it pops back up whenever the mouse is inactive (regardless of keyboard input), and ignores the mouse while the mouse is captured by an application for some bizarre reason, making it extremely difficult to test applications. I am running a Raspberry Pi Model 2 B (V 1.1 if it matters), and it has a reliable 2.1 A power source. Running the latest version of Raspbian Jessie.

Is there any way of disabling this behaviour, so that the screen does not sleep, regardless of the mouse state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `avoid_warnings=2` in `config.txt` to use the open driver, or this will happen.

What's happening is the firmware is stomping over the graphics state (specifically the display planes) to show the undervoltage warning, and you only recover when the driver reconfigures planes itself (which is when the cursor moves or pageflips happen)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Why is the undervolt warning getting triggered?

Comment: A lot of USB cables and ports aren't up to spec, and the symptom is the voltage dropping.  Raspberry Pi throws up a warning when it gets low, so you have a warning before the system just hangs.

Comment: That would make sense actually. The cable connecting the battery pack and the pi on this setup gets very hot during use, seems to be wasting a lot of energy in transmission.